# Hive create new table failed

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have installed hadoop cluster and hive, but when I create a new table, it returned the following error

```
hive> create table newtb (a int, b int, c int) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';
Moved: 'hdfs://hadoop-master:54310/user/hive/warehouse/newtb' to trash at: hdfs://hadoop-master:54310/user/hadoop/.Trash/Current
Moved: 'hdfs://hadoop-master:54310/user/hive/warehouse/newtb' to trash at: hdfs://hadoop-master:54310/user/hadoop/.Trash/Current
Moved: 'hdfs://hadoop-master:54310/user/hive/warehouse/newtb' to trash at: hdfs://hadoop-master:54310/user/hadoop/.Trash/Current
Moved: 'hdfs://hadoop-master:54310/user/hive/warehouse/newtb' to trash at: hdfs://hadoop-master:54310/user/hadoop/.Trash/Current
Moved: 'hdfs://hadoop-master:54310/user/hive/warehouse/newtb' to trash at: hdfs://hadoop-master:54310/user/hadoop/.Trash/Current
Moved: 'hdfs://hadoop-master:54310/user/hive/warehouse/newtb' to trash at: hdfs://hadoop-master:54310/user/hadoop/.Trash/Current
Moved: 'hdfs://hadoop-master:54310/user/hive/warehouse/newtb' to trash at: hdfs://hadoop-master:54310/user/hadoop/.Trash/Current
Moved: 'hdfs://hadoop-master:54310/user/hive/warehouse/newtb' to trash at: hdfs://hadoop-master:54310/user/hadoop/.Trash/Current
Moved: 'hdfs://hadoop-master:54310/user/hive/warehouse/newtb' to trash at: hdfs://hadoop-master:54310/user/hadoop/.Trash/Current
Moved: 'hdfs://hadoop-master:54310/user/hive/warehouse/newtb' to trash at: hdfs://hadoop-master:54310/user/hadoop/.Trash/Current
Moved: 'hdfs://hadoop-master:54310/user/hive/warehouse/newtb' to trash at: hdfs://hadoop-master:54310/user/hadoop/.Trash/Current
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:For direct MetaStore DB connections, we don't support retries at the client level.)
hive>
```

How to solve it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set charset in the MySQL

```
$ mysql -uroot -p
mysql> alter database hivedb character set latin1;
```

Then, you can create your table.